# Invalid Content-Length and HTTP 413 error?

Tags: php, linux, apache2, cgi, mailman

I'm stack because all the websites on my Linux Apache2 web server which have a form to fulfil are returning 413 Request Entity Too Large Error **only after first fulfil (refresh makes it working)**. Error looks like:

```
Request Entity Too Large

The requested resource
/mailman/subscribe/konrad
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided in the    request exceeds the capacity limit.

Request Entity Too Large

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Here is apache2 error log:

```
[Tue Dec 04 12:06:27 2012] [error] [client 5.184.118.16] Invalid Content-Length, referer:   http://62.87.177.20/mailman/admindb/konrad
[Tue Dec 04 12:06:27 2012] [error] [client 5.184.118.16] (-3)Unknown error 4294967293:    Error reading request entity data, referer: http://62.87.177.20/mailman/admindb/konrad
[Tue Dec 04 12:07:12 2012] [error] [client 46.134.87.133] Invalid Content-Length, referer: http://www.comfortzg.com/~lekumed2010/login.php?PHPSESSID=e6b9c4d160a2b06435bb8c0676acbe51
```

It gives the error on both (one using PHP and second Perl (cgi)) scripts. I'm not using SSL.

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with the problem. But do you have Gzip compression enabled? Might try to disable it.. That is where I would start looking..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the form is submitted using the GET http method but the url built by the browser is too long. In this case the usual server answer is HTTP Error 413 **Request** entity too large.

In this case you should use POST method to figure out this problem.

Comment: thank you for answer, bo no, it is POST, I've added an error text to the question

Comment: have you changed the apache and/or php configuration during these days? consider to build a simple php page with `phpinfo()` inside to double check the php configuration.